# Update a record based on a related column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column - say, article_id - that corresponds to the primary key of another table. See below.

I want to populate the column 'lev' with the Levenshtein Distance, calculated as such:

```
LEVENSHTEIN(table1.string, table2.title)
```

...where the article_id of table1 corresponds to the primary key of table2.

I'm using Postgres and this function is part of the fuzzystrmatch module.

The relevant part of the tables look like this:

```
table1
id    article_id   string   lev
1     134          'ace'
2     227          'bdg'
3     425          'hkl'

table2
id    title
134   'Some title abc'
227   'Some title def'
425   'Some title ghi'
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing anything about the library module you referenced, assuming the function exists, this should work:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 
SET lev = LEVENSHTEIN(t1.string,t2.title)
FROM table2 as t2
WHERE t1.articleid = t2.id
```

Comment: Very simple. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table1 as t1 SET lev=LEVENSHTEIN(t1.string, t2.title)
FROM table2 as t2
WHERE t1.article_id = t2.id
```

Useful reference:

- [Update syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)